# Facebook Graph API Video Upload Privacy Setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to set the "privacy" for each video upload using the Graph API?
I have a little gallery that will display different videos from people. But at the moment, I can only display the Thumbnail and unable to view the video if I am not "friends" with the uploader.

FYI: I have set the "Default Activity Privacy" in the Facebook App setting in Auth Dialog to "Everyone".

Any inputs would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to **Account Settings** >> **Apps**, and find your app, there is a settings called

> Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook profile?

While your *Default Activity Privacy* may be set to *Everyone* **now**, it's possible that when the user authorized the app, he changed the privacy mode. Or, maybe the user authorized your app with the default privacy *before* you changed the default.

---

via Facebook: ["Where can I control my app privacy and settings?"](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=218345114850283)

... never does Facebook say that an app can override a user's privacy setting. That's because it's not possible. If it were possible, it would seriously discourage people from using apps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gil. So, there is no way to upload a video and set the privacy for the uploaded video (to public)? I just realized that it would be something like "over-riding" the default privacy setting and would actually be a "privacy issue" if developers are allowed to do this. But still maybe there is way that I do not know about.

Comment: Facebook privacy settings is exactly for the purpose of preventing anything from being published publicly without the user's express permission.

Answer (score 0):

@Gil Birman answer is wrong.

Try add to http entity param with name `privacy` and value `{"value":"SELF"}`. As result, uploaded video have access: only me. Facebook support also other privacy.